# Python match string to string exactly

Tags: python, text, nltk

Given a string, I want to identify whether a two strings are within it. For example, given "The dog barks loudly .", I want to search for "dog" and "barks loudly". If the sentence were "The dogged man .", however, I would NOT want to match 'dog' to 'dogged'.

I am using the following:

```
if re.search(r'\s'+word+'\s', str1) and re.search(r'\s'+otherWord+'\s', str1) and word != otherWord:
```

My question is 1. If every punctuation had a space before it, would my method work? 2. Is there a better way to do it so that I don't have to pre-process the string to put a space in front of every punctuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use word boundary `\b` (*which matches between a word character and a non-word character*) instead of space `\s`. And also you need to define all the regex patterns as raw string.

```
if re.search(r'\b'+word+r'\b', str1) and re.search(r'\b'+otherWord+r'\b', str1) and word != otherWord:
```

Comment: Can you explain "define regex patterns as raw string"?

Comment: You correctly define the first pattern `r'\s'` as raw string but in the second case `'\s'`, you failed to do that. If you failed to define a pattern as raw string, you must need to escape all the backslashes present in that pattern to  one more time like `'\\s'`